# Compartilhamento P2P com PHP?

Tags: php, bittorrent, blockchain

Bem, a algum tempo venho estudando sobre blockchain, consequentemente redes p2p, até que cheguei no IPFS e achei bem legal isso tudo, porem, não achei nada em PHP, geralmente as implementações de redes p2p são feitas em Golang ou Python. Tenho algumas dúvidas sobre isso:

1. Numa rede p2p, como um peer encontra o outro?
2. Existe alguma implementação desses protocolos p2p em PHP?
3. Estou estudando isso no intuito de fazer uma especie de smart contract em PHP, será viável?

Obrigado a todos, se eu conseguir boas respostas talvez isso vire um artigo acadêmico.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP é uma linguagem que foi criada com foco em gerar páginas dinâmicas em HTML, e embora tenha evoluído para uma linguagem de propósito geral, não incorporou  a melhor opção das ferramentas necessárias para aplicações genéricas - assim, é possível criar uma rede P2P e implementar protocolos de redes já existentes em PHP, mas pelo fato de não ser a melhor ferramenta para isso, não foi feito. Seria perigoso especular o por quê disso aqui, porque eu não conseguiria ser objetivo. Tudo que é necessário para implementar qualquer protocolo de rede é que exista [uma API para sockets puros](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), e uma forma de manipular bytes e bits - o restante é uma questão de quanto é prático, na sintaxe da linguagem escrever código conciso, limpo, com boas prátias de segurança e de fácil manutençã.

Já, quanto a smart contracts, aí é outra história - as blockchains que permitem smart contracts fazem isso com um bytecode específico, que é executado nos nós da chain, e tem uma ou mais linguagens criadas específicamente para criar smart-contracts naquela chain (a exceção que conheço é o EOS que usa C++). Mas, se pegar o Ethereum por exemplo, que é provavelmente a blockchain mais popular para smartcontracts - ela tem 2 ou 3 linguagens distintas, mas próprias dela, para criação dos smartcontracts - a mais populares sendo uma mais parecida, mas sem ser, Javascript (solidity) e outra parecida, mas sem ser, Python (Vyper).

Quanto a primeira parte, de "como um peer encontra outro" - na configuração de cada projeto P2P há uma listagem de "parceiros iniciais" - é até uma forma de centralização - mas nada impede que forks do código troquem essa lista inicial de parceiros conhecidos, e, de qualquer forma, eles são só configuração. E, dentre as chamadas que são feitas automaticamente para os outros nós, sempre há chamadas para pesquisar outros nós parceiros, e um algoritmo bem feito vai repetindo essas chamadas para escolher nós mais distantes, diferentes, mas com um bom tempo de resposta - dessa forma, as informações sobre nós distantes vão se propagando e a rede mantém seu caráter descentralizado, mesmo cada nó "zerado" começando com uma lista fixa de parceiros.

Comment: Agora - se me permite puxar um pouco de brasa, fora do texto da resposta: aprenda Python. Vale a pena se está atrás desse tipo de coisa.